# itemrendrer checkbox in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, checkbox, itemrenderer

How can i make the checkBox click as disable in itemRendrer in a datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:HBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" paddingLeft="3">
            <mx:CheckBox name="chkBoxSel" selected="false" enabled="false"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```